# (bash) Indenting multiple lines of text to $VAR with cat?

Tags: linux, bash, eof, heredoc

**OS:** Debian 7 Wheezy GNU\Linux
**Language:** Bash
**Documents reviewed already:** [wiki/heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

What works:

```
cat > software.temp <<- EOF 
gparted 
baobab 
EOF
```

What doesn't

```
prefer="/etc/apt/preferences.d/${reponame}"
cat <<- EOF >> ${prefer}
Package: *
Pin: release l=Debian
Pin-Priority: 110
EOF
```

Yes, I know it's in reverse, which is probably what I'm not getting it to work. Essentially getting the age old "can't find EOF" error. Please note **each block above is indented** with TAB once or more. You can see my code [here](https://github.com/ProfessorKaos64/SteamOS-Tools/blob/testing/add-debian-repos.sh#L57). I wonder if it is because of how I am trying to direct the input/output.

I had maybe thought something like the below was it, but that didn't work either.

```
cat <<- EOF 
Package: *
Pin: release l=Debian
Pin-Priority: 110
EOF >> ${prefer}
```

Comment: You can put I/O redirections before or after the here-doc.  If you want to pipe the output of the here-doc, the pipe must go after it: `cat file - <<-EOF | whatever` (where the `whatever` - the command to receive the output - can be on a separate line after the end of the here-doc).  Be wary of not enclosing the word for the here-doc in quotes (`<<- 'EOF'); the shell expands variables and `$(...)` command-substitutions (and the back-quote version too) if you don't use the quoted 'word' form.

Comment: I tried `cat - <<- EOF | cat >> ${prefer}` but that didn't seem to work (ending with EOF. You can checkout my [code](https://github.com/ProfessorKaos64/SteamOS-Tools/blob/testing/add-debian-repos.sh#L74) if it helps.

Comment: You're on Debian?  Are you sure your script isn't being run by `dash` rather than `bash`?  The two behave differently in some respects, and I'm not sure whether the handling of here-docs isn't one of those ways.  What do you see when you run `bash -x add-debian-repos.sh`?  Does it behave differently with `dash -x add-debian-repos.sh` or `sh -x add-debian-repos.sh`?  Can you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that doesn't modify anyone's system administration stuff but does demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Still the same with `/bin/bash add-debian-repos`. You can compare [what works](https://github.com/ProfessorKaos64/SteamOS-Tools/blob/master/add-debian-repos.sh#L52) with [what does not work](https://github.com/ProfessorKaos64/SteamOS-Tools/blob/testing/add-debian-repos.sh#L73) for reference. Those are the lines from my stable/testing branches, respectively. Thank you for your help Jonathan. dash gives me "unterminated quote string", with bash giving "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: You have a space between the `<<` or `<<-` and the word.  The POSIX docs ([Here document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)) show no space.  This is clutching at straws, though; I can't find a difference with bash, dash or sh on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS derivative) using my test code (which is only loosely based on yours).  From the download, you appear to have tabs in the indent, so you should be OK.  (This gives me a problem; local coding standards are tab-less, so it requires shenanigans to get tabs into a file.)

Comment: Yea, I've tried with no space, I know it makes no functional difference, but glad to know that no space is POSIX compatible. If you were to clone my repository, then `git checkout testing` you could then see 1:1 what I am seeing and editing. I truly appreciate the help. It's frustrating. I try to maintain neat code, so it's been bugging me.

Comment: @ProfessorKaos64 you led us to totally wrong direction. your script is broken at line 117: `echo -e "proceeding.\n""`  you have an extra double quotes `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer use `cat -A`  and make sure there is no space between `EOF` and the end of the line.

---

Two things about `here-doc`:

1. make sure the line ends straight after the string you picked usually `EOF` but it could be anything.
2. `-` in `cat <<-EOF` allows indentation so lines can start with tabs and those tabs will not be printed.

Examples:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
Hello here-doc
EOF

tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
Hello here-doc
EOF 

tiago@dell:/tmp$ bash test1.sh
Hello here-doc

tiago@dell:/tmp$ bash test2.sh
test2.sh: line 4: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
Hello here-doc
EOF
```

Those two files look identical but on test2.sh there is a space  after EOF which can't be noticed on text  editor, but you can use `cat -A`:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat -A test1.sh
#!/bin/bash$
cat << EOF$
Hello here-doc$
EOF$

tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat -A test2.sh
#!/bin/bash$
cat << EOF$
Hello here-doc$
EOF $
```

Now WRT indentation:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat test3.sh 
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
    Hello here-doc
EOF

cat <<-EOF 
    Hello here-doc (Indentation ignored)
EOF

tiago@dell:/tmp$ bash test3.sh
    Hello here-doc
Hello here-doc (Indentation ignored)
```

Comment: This is some great info, but doesn't solve the use case I have. I have a link to my code above. If you don't mind, could you please see if you could make this work or advise on how to approach it? To be safe, of course, just change the vars in funct_set_vars to temp files.

Comment: @ProfessorKaos64 take a look @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/10731995/ I isolated your scenario. Mind you that when you use `cat <<-EOF` only tabs are ignored therefore if there are spaces before `EOF` instead of tabs it won't work. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I checked before and now that the EOF after the block text did not have a any spaces around it. While your example has `^I` , mine has two, `^I^I` as I have two tabs up to the block. I backed the whole section up one TAB level to produce what you have. My end of line `$` is where yours is, as well as my preceding tabs with `^I` . I even change my prefer $VAR to `/tmp/file` as well. What would def. tell  me I am hopeless, is if you obtained my testing script, and changed the `perfer=` var at the top. IF that works for you, idk what I'm doing wrong haha. Your test file code did work.

Comment: @ProfessorKaos64 you led us to totally wrong direction. your script is broken at line 117: `echo -e "proceeding.\n""`  you have an extra double quotes `:)`

Comment: OMG Tiago!!! Welp, so much for double-blind tests with shellcheck.net! I can't thank you enough. I knew just a bit ago it had* to be something else in the code. You made my day! Thank you as well Jonathan!